# How to change XAMPP Software installation date in Windows?

Tags: windows, xampp, regedit

There is no XAMPP entry in regedit when trying to access
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall or
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Anybody knows how to change installation date manually?

Comment: have you tried to dig in HKCU (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER`) instead?

Comment: don't see in HKEY_CURRENT_USER any installation date possibilities for any programs